have someone to do something
I recently came across a non-native English teacher writing the following in a grammar exercise:
The sports day is next Friday. We will have the final-year students to help us with the sports day. They will be selling tickets to parents and friends who would like to join the day.
I only know the construction "have someone do something", and have never seen "have someone to do something" before. Is the second construction possible? And in the example I quoted, should it be "help" instead of "to help"?

This isn't the same as "we will have them help". This is more like "we will have them" [at the sports day], and so they will be able to help.

Thanks, Daniel. Does it then mean that the original sentence is fine (with the use of "have the final-year students to help"), with the meaning of "the final-year students will be available to help"? If so, is this use common and idiomatic?

Compare: Do you have your umbrella with you today, to keep yourself dry?

"to help us" just makes it a to-infinitive clause in the sense of purpose.

In the sentence We will have the final-year students to help us with the sports day, the construction have X to Y means, essentially “benefit from X’s doing Y.” Thus the title of the popular standard (song) “I’ve Got My Love to Keep Me Warm.” Likewise, one might reply to a child’s query, “No, the baseball players don’t mow the field. The team has a groundskeeper to do that.”
So your sentence means that the speaker is confident that the sports day will not be a problem because the final-year students can be relied on for assistance in running it. A paraphrase is We will have the final-year students; they will help us with the sports day

The OP's final question is:

In the example I quoted, should it be "help" instead of "to help"?

Other answers are good and should be read carefully. But to focus on this question specifically, the answer is: Both options are correct, but they mean different things. So the choice (as so often) depends on what you want to say.

We will have the final-year students to help us with the sports day.

This means: The final-year students will be at the sports day, so they will be extra people available to help.

We will have the final-year students help us with the sports day.

This means: We will arrange for the final-year students to be at the sports day so they can help.

I’d say the latter means more specifically we will arrange for the final-year students to help or even we will order the final-year students to help, rather than simply arranging for them to be there so they can help.

I think there's a confusion between two similar constructions.

Have someone do something
WILL have someone TO do something

Construction number 1 -
To have someone do something - means: some explicit/implicit agent will delegate to someone the (task of) something (at some indefinite time in the future).
e.g
[I'll/I will] have my people call your people.
[Let's/Let us] have our lawyers negotiate terms.
Construction number 2 -
We will have someone to do something - means: the agent will have the assistance of someone to do something ( on the specific future occasion under disussion )
e.g
In that noisy atmosphere at least Billy will have his emotional support dog to keep him calm.
At least Billy will have his emotional support dog to keep him calm in that noisy atmosphere.
With/without "to"
We will/We'll have our lawyers negotiate terms.
Sense: Delegation
We will/We'll have our lawyers to negotiate terms.
Sense: Assistance
N.B This sentence may be constructed as so without changing the sense:
We will/We'll have our lawyers negotiating terms.
Sense: Assistance
Hope this helps. Apologies if I've over-explained.. I'm working on it!

You have complicated your answer unnecessarily: the difference has nothing to do with the presence or absence  of will (the tense of have). The only relevant difference is the presence or absence of to before the bare infinitive.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Re: un-clarity. I suspected as much. Mr Tanenbaum, respectfully I'm not sure how to take your feedback on board practically. Thank you for it, though. Currently reading how to write clearer answers in the help centre.
